# displays channels[object Object] instead of the real values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I am working on an application using reactjs. I set the default to array and got arrays of values from firebase but what it displays is objects instead of the real values. if I console the values from firebase it displays the values but when I add it to the channels and loop through the array it shows channels[Object object]

```
const [channels, setChannels] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
db.collection('channels').onSnapshot((snapshot) =>
    setChannels(
        snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            channel: doc.data()
        }))
    )
);
```

}, [])

```
{channels.map(({ channel, id }) => (
                <SidebarChannel
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    channelName={channel}
                />
            ))}
```

This is the output from firebase

[image]

Comment: That just means your `channel` data is a JSON object. can you try console logging it and paste it in your question?

Comment: What is happening is, you are passing an object to a place string is expected. Due to this your object is converted to string (`[Object object]`). Instead, pass necessary value. `={channel.property}`

Comment: i just posted an answer @mychuks

Comment: @syedmh "JSON object" you mean it's a JavaScript object.

Comment: @phuzi you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your `console.log`, the way you need to get this information on your front-end is by passing in `channel.channelName` instead of `channel`. Your code would have to be this:

```
{channels.map(({ channel, id }) => (
                <SidebarChannel
                    key={id}
                    id={id}
                    channelName={channel.channelName}
                />
            ))}
```

The reason it wasn't working earlier is because `channel` is still an Object even if it just has one property inside of it.